# am trying to sorts the result of an histogram in c

Tags: arrays, c, sorting

hi i wrote the code below to give the histogram of the occurrence of each number in a matrix

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, j, existe, k, n, size, tab[10][10], elements[100], histo[100];
  do {
    printf("\n Entrer la taille de la matrice : ");
    scanf("%d", & n);
  } while (n <= 0 || n > 50);
  /* TAKING MATRIX INPUT */
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      printf(" tab[%d][%d]=", i, j);
      scanf("%d", & tab[i][j]);
    }
  }
  /* MATRIX DISPLAY */
  printf("\nla matrice:");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\n");
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      printf("%4d", tab[i][j]);
  }

  /* initialization of the array 'elements' */
  elements[0] = tab[0][0];
  size = 0; //size' is the size of the array 'elements'

  /*filling the array 'elements'*/
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      existe = 0;
      for (k = 0; k <= size; k++)
        if (elements[k] == tab[i][j]) {
          existe = 1;
          break;
        }
        if (!existe) {
        size++;
        elements[size] = tab[i][j];
      }
    }
  }

  /*display of the array 'elements'*/
  printf("\n Affichage du tableau elements \n");
  for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    printf("%d ", elements[i]);

  /* initialization of the array 'histo' */
  for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    histo[i] = 0;

  /*filling the array 'histo' */
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      for (k = 0; k <= size; k++)
        if (elements[k] == tab[i][j]) {
          histo[k] += 1;
          break;
        }
    }
  }

  /*Affichage du tableau histo */
  printf("\n Affichage du tableau histo \n");
  for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    printf("%d ", histo[i]);

  /display of the histogram/
  printf("\n");
  printf("\n Affichage de l\'histogramme \n");
  for (i = 0; i <= size; i++) {
    printf("\n %d : ", elements[i]);
    for (j = 0; j < histo[i]; j++)
      printf("* ");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

the resolt for example is given as this

```
 Entrer la taille de la matrice : 4
 tab[0][0]=3
 tab[0][1]=2
 tab[0][2]=5
 tab[0][3]=3
 tab[1][0]=5
 tab[1][1]=5
 tab[1][2]=2
 tab[1][3]=3
 tab[2][0]=3
 tab[2][1]=2
 tab[2][2]=3
 tab[2][3]=5
 tab[3][0]=5
 tab[3][1]=3
 tab[3][2]=3
 tab[3][3]=3

la matrice:
   3   2   5   3
   5   5   2   3
   3   2   3   5
   5   3   3   3
 Affichage du tableau elements
3 2 5
 Affichage du tableau histo
8 3 5

 Affichage de l'histogramme

 3 : * * * * * * * *
 2 : * * *
 5 : * * * * *
```

i need the histogram to be sorted from lowest to highest
ie
2 : * * *
3 : * * * * * * * *
5 : * * * * *

i tried to sort the array elements like this

```
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) 
        {
 
            for (j = i + 1; j < size; ++j)
            {
 
                if (elements[i] > elements[j]) 
                {
 
                    a =  elements[i];
                    elements[i] = elements[j];
                    elements[j] = a;
 
                }
 
            }
 
        }
```

what i got is the elements ordre changed the the starts didnt
2:* * * * * * * *
3:* * *
5:* * * * *
what do i do
this is not a homework its just and exercice form the internet dont ban my questions pllz

Comment: Why don't you use [qsort](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm)?

Comment: Aside: You take `n` as a value in the range [1, 50], but use it as the upper bounds for indexing an array defined as `int tab[10][10]`. Valid indices in either dimension are [0, 9]. That's a lot of room for [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior). `while (n <= 0 || n > 50)` should be `while (n <= 0 || n > 10)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort `histo` and `elements` at the same time, based on the values in `elements`.

You need to use `size` here, not `n`.

```
for (i = 0; i <= size; ++i) {
    for (j = i + 1; j <= size; ++j) {    
        if (elements[i] > elements[j]) {    
            a = histo[i];     
            histo[i] = histo[j];    
            histo[j] = a;    
                
            a = elements[i];     
            elements[i] = elements[j];    
            elements[j] = a;    
        }    
    }    
}
```

---

Note that

```
elements[0] = tab[0][0];
size = 0; //size' is the size of the array 'elements'
```

is misleading. `size` is used throughout your code as the maximum valid index for `elements` and `histo`. A much more common idiom is to keep track of the number of elements in an array, and instead check that your current index is less than that count (e.g., `i < size`).

Something like

```
/* remove this `elements[0] = tab[0][0];` OR initialize size to 1*/
size = 0; /* size' is the COUNT of the array 'elements' */

/*filling the array 'elements'*/
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        int existe = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++)
            if (elements[k] == tab[i][j]) {
                existe = 1;
                break;
            }

        if (!existe) {
            elements[size] = tab[i][j];
            size++; /* start from 0 and increase the index AFTER assignment */
        }
    }
}
```

Then change every `<= size` to `< size`.

Comment: this is what i got 
 2 : * * *
 5 : * * * * *
 3 : * * * * * * * *

Comment: @med Oh, you want to sort the values themselves, not the frequencies. Then sort by comparing the values in `elements`, as you had, but also sort `histo` the same way.

Comment: it worked when i changed the condition to if (elements[i] > elements[j])

Comment: @med That's great! Make sure to read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) to learn how to mark this question as resolved.